# Filtering Powershell result in For Each statement

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, intune, windows-defender, microsoft-graph-intune

I've written (or trying to write atleast) a simple script to get all Microsoft Intune Defender Policies that are a assigned to a specific Azure AD group.

The scripts gets all Defender policies, finds the group ID linked to those policies and then it gets the actual name using Get-AzureADGroup.

Now I need to find a way to only show the policy that matches a specific group name (hard-coded). At the top of the script I have a variable with the group name. I just can't find a way on how to filter all the $intent(s) to only show the ones linked to the group name variable.

```
Connect-MSGraph -ForceInteractive
Update-MSGraphEnvironment -SchemaVersion beta
Connect-MSGraph
Connect-AzureAD

$groupname = "group-name-here"

$intents = Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod GET -Url "deviceManagement/intents" | Get-MSGraphAllPages


 foreach ($intent in $intents) {
        $PolicyID = Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod GET -Url "deviceManagement/intents/$($intent.Id)/assignments"
        $AssignmentGroupIDs = $PolicyID.value.target.groupID

            foreach ($AssignmentGroupID in $AssignmentGroupIDs) {
                $AssignmentGroupName = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $AssignmentGroupID

            }
        }


Write-Host "Number of policies found: $($intents.Id.Count)" -ForegroundColor cyan
Write-Host $AssignmentGroupName.DisplayName
Write-Host $intent.displayName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any value you create and *don't* assign to a variable will be part of the script block's output. That means you can do things like this:

```
$result = foreach (...) {
     if (condition) {
         $value
     }
}
```

and `$result` will contain all the `$value`s from the loop.

In context (untested, but you get the idea):

```
$matchingIntents = foreach ($intent in $intents) {
    $PolicyID = Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod GET -Url "deviceManagement/intents/$($intent.Id)/assignments"
    $AssignmentGroupIDs = $PolicyID.value.target.groupID
    foreach ($AssignmentGroupID in $AssignmentGroupIDs) {
        $AssignmentGroupName = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $AssignmentGroupID
        if ($AssignmentGroupName -eq $groupname) {
            $intent
            break
        }
    }
}
```